# trouble including PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.3

I want to start writing tests for my code so I installed the latest PHPUnit with the following commands

```
wget http://pear.phpunit.de/get/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/installation.html

then I added /usr/local/bin to my php.ini include path which looks like this

`include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php:/usr/local/bin"`

but I'm getting the following errors when I visit `/my-app/test.php`

> Warning (2): include(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory
>   [CORE/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php, line 150]
>
> Warning (2): include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/Users/DevinCrossman/Sites/studio-bliss/lib:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php:/usr/local/bin')
>   [CORE/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php, line 150]

I tried changing `/usr/local/bin/phpunit` to `/usr/local/bin/PHPUnit` but that didn't work. I also tried changing the include path from `/usr/local/bin` to `/usr/local/bin/phpunit` and restarted apache (I'm using MAMP PRO on this machine but it also didn't work on my ubuntu server)

a `phpinfo()` shows the include path is being set correctly.

it's probably something obvious that I've missed. Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CakePHP recommends using PEAR to install PHPUnit](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html). It should work better in your case.

Putting the phar in /usr/local/bin with filename 'phpunit' is meant to be used by running [PHPUnit's testrunner via the command line](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/textui.html) as it will make the phpunit command available. e.g. running command:

```
phpunit MyTest test.php
```

When running in the browser, you need the PHPUnit classes available to load which does not work by simply having the path to your phar in the include path.
I'm not sure but it may work if you include the phar in your test file:

```
require_once '/path/to/phpunit.phar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit or create *composer.json* in *app* directory. Add following lines.

```
{
    "require-dev" : {"phpunit/phpunit":"3.7.*"}
}
```

Then install using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

```
composer install
```