# Installing PHPUnit in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am running a cakePHP (2.3.9) app and would like to start unit testing. I seem to need the PHPUnit installed but the instructions tell to use PEAR installer.

The PEAR installer in cPanel (app is running on shared hosting) only suggests PHPUnit version 2.3.6 when the latest stable version is already 4.3

I have done research, but I dont seem to find a proper solution on how to get it running.

Is there anyone who has faced the same problem and found a way out?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: For 2.x the adviced way would be to just use composer (for your whole app incl. CakePHP) :-) Then everything works out of the box. If you cant just yet, you can also use https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-phpunit by the way. Also works out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

PHPUnit 4.x is **not** compatible with CakePHP 2.x, you should use PHPUnit 3.7.x

[See doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html)

Comment: Thanks for this note, but after I download it, what should I do? That is the main concern. I would get by with just step by step instruction on how to instal it.
I have not found any proper manual for that.

Comment: Try following the installation notes found in the CakePHP doc, the link in my response, it should work as is. I am not sure it is a good idea to unitTest the app that is deployed on a remote server, I would do it locally.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download phar archive (executable PHP file) which contains PHPUnit version 4.3

https://phpunit.de/

Or use composer.json and composer to import PHPUnit library.

https://getcomposer.org/

You probably won't be able to change PEAR settings without root access to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would rather prefer to download a phar archive. But what's next after I have downloaded it?

Comment: Do you have the shell access to the server or do you know how is PHPUnit run in CakePHP ? Probably you will have to change the path to PHPUnit in startup script to PHPUnit.phar file. I usually just invoke phpunit.phar from shell with arguments which tell where the test suites are. Dont forget to add +x permission with chmod to the phar archive.

Comment: The problem is that I know nothing of the above. I did research and tried to get it to run, but I just get completely lost.
I do not know how PHPUnit is run in CakePHP, what the test suites and +x permission is.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392089/trouble-including-phpunit. You may not have to change file permissions, just add require_once to the test case. It is not a very nice solution tho. CakePHP requires upnacked PHPUnit in Vendor folder (which is meant to be loaded using PHPUnit Autoloader). Also keep in mind, that CakePHP 2 is not compatible with PHPUnit 4 (no autoloader there). Otherwise I would try writing shell script for testing.

Comment: I still do not really get it and I believe I am not the only one. Creating and running the tests is not going to be the problem, but what is the step by step procedure of installing PHPUnit? I have already downloaded the PHAR archive, but what then?